# system.data.common.datarecordinternal in dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

[image: Sample Picture]
After compiling I get an error

> system.data.common.datarecordinternal in datalistview

It must get the data inside the database.

```
Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=11.123.123.32;Initial Catalog=RESERVATION_SYSTEM;User Id=**;Password=***"

        Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
                Using con As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
                    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("Select [Room] FROM [RESERVATION_SYSTEM].[dbo].[LMO_RESERVATION_SYSTEM_ROOM]", con)
                    con.Open()
                    Dim rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                    roomType.DataSource = rdr
                    roomType.DataBind()
                    roomType.DataTextField = "RESERVATION_SYSTEM"
                End Using
                roomType.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("--Select Room --"))
            End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://forums.asp.net/t/1908659.aspx?Dropdownlist%20contains%20info%20as%20system%20data%20common%20datarecordinternal%20after%20binding) helped to solve my problem. Before databind you need to include which column you will select in table.

```
roomType.DataTextField = "ROOM"
roomType.DataValueField = "ROOM"
```

Comment: That is great! I think it is a matter of language but I don't think this is a row you are selecting. It is a column (field). Rows are records. Columns have names like ID, Name, Address etc.

Comment: oh yes. That's what I meant. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: Aha! I was adding that line after databind() silly me!